# Let $f: P →Q$. Let $A ⊆ P$ and $B ⊆ P$. Show that $f(A ∩ B) ⊆ f(A) ∩ f(B)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f: P →Q$. Let $A ⊆ P$ and $B ⊆ P$. Show that $f(A ∩ B) ⊆ f(A) ∩ f(B)$.

How can I prove this? I thought of picking an arbitrary element $x$ to be in both sets, but I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: It will be more convenient for you if you learn to format on this site. Use `$f:P\to Q, A\subseteq P$` to show $f:P\to Q, A\subseteq P$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z\in f(A\cap B)$, then there exists $x\in A\cap B$ such that $f(x)=z$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ by the definition of intersection and so $z\in f(A)$ and $z\in f(B)$. Therefore we get $z\in f(A)\cap f(B)$.